# Double type DependencyProperties has wrong values in WinRT

Tags: double, windows-runtime, dependency-properties

I have a custom control with a dependency property of double type. When I set this property from XAML, say I am giving 12.34 as value to this property. The property changed call back giving the value as 12.3400001525879, the actual value has trailing garbage decimal values.

(This is not the case for Silverlight)

This happens only when we set the value through XAML, and also it happens only if we have more than one decimal value.

```
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(TextBoxExt), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);//Not priniting the exact value.
    }
```

Does anyone facing the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not all decimal values are exactly representable by fixed-width binary floating point types like `float` and `double`.  Decimal values that are not exactly representable (like 12.34) are rounded to the nearest value that is representable.  You can read all about floating point types in David Goldberg's excellent article, ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic."](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

In this case, the actual values you mention indicate that either (a) the value 12.34 is being parsed as a `float` or (b) it is being converted to a `float` at some point.  This is a bit odd, but may either be by design or a bug.  Whether or not it is a bug, if you use floating point types in your software, you need to account for potential rounding error.

Comment: My test was with use of doubles solely. I also suspected there might be some sort of problem with the double representing the number, but since setting the value from code behind works without any problem - it seems like as you said - the built in default type converter for double-typed properties parses string values as floats.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the same problem in my testing. Looks clearly like a bug in Jupiter. I would report it in MSDN Forums.